# QGraphicsItem multiple class inheritance not working

Tags: python

Why does this multiple class inheritance not work? It appears I'm doing something incorrect. I'm trying to create a baseclass that has a property of UID and when that property is change it calls self.update forcing the graphics item's paint event to be triggered. The reason for the baseclass is so i can implement this property across all other custom GraphicItems that I'll be eventually creating. Not all of them will be TextItems.

```
import os, sys, uuid
from Qt import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class AbstractNodeItem(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(AbstractNodeItem, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFlags(self.ItemIsSelectable | self.ItemIsMovable)
        self.setZValue(0)

        # private
        self.m_uid = uuid.uuid4().hex

    # Getters/Setters
    def getUid(self):
        return self.m_uid

    def setUid(self, value=''):
        self.m_uid = value


class StickyNoteNodeItem(AbstractNodeItem, QtWidgets.QGraphicsTextItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(StickyNoteNodeItem, self).__init__(parent)


def printProperties(item):
    print '>>>>>', item.getUid()


a = AbstractNodeItem()
b = StickyNoteNodeItem()
printProperties(a)
printProperties(b)
```

Comment: change  `class AbstractNodeItem(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem):` to `class AbstractNodeItem(object):` and remove `a = AbstractNodeItem()` and `printProperties(a)`

Comment: is doing multiple class inheristance bad if i plan on converting this to C++ qt?

Comment: Not really, but the concept you should use is an interface.

Comment: I agree, im not sure how to do that in pyside using python? Is that something I would do in Qt with C++ when i convert it?

Comment: Although the concepts and implementations are similar in C ++ and python, there are slight differences that I would recommend you to try. And obviously test the concept first in basic classes (not Qt) since Qt has other restrictions.

Comment: if you want all the QGraphicsItems to have the same class AbstractNodeItem I would recommend using templates in C++

Comment: I'm assuming some of the stuff you describe is not easily done in python pyside, which is why im doing it here first because it's easier and quicker to do